# How to get at most two entries for each name in the where clause

Tags: mysql

What I'm trying to accomplish is select multiple values with a limit.

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE name IN ('Tom', 'Tommy') LIMIT 2
```

I understand this query won't work as needed, but it's just an example.
I can't quite wrap my head around on the situation

My desired output is:

```
id
1
5
4
8
```

Just to make it clear, LIMIT will return {limit} rows PER variable.

LIMIT 3 would return 3 rows per

```
id
1
5
6
4
8
```

Table:

```
id, name
1, Tom
2, Jeff
3, Jason
4, Tommy
5, Tom
6, Tom
7, Jeff
8, Tommy
```

Comment: So your requirement is : you want at most two entries for each name?

Comment: Wo how is it decided that 6 is the one to be left out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the query:

```
SELECT 
t.id,
t.name
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    id,
    `name`,
    IF(@prevName = `name`, @nameRank := @nameRank + 1, @nameRank := 0) rank,
    @prevName := `name`
    FROM your_table, (SELECT @prevName := NULL, @nameRank := 0) var
    WHERE `name` IN ('Tom','Tommy')
    ORDER BY `name`,id
) t
WHERE t.rank < 2
ORDER BY t.id;
```

**Note:** You need to put the limit here `WHERE t.rank < LIMIT`

---

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/657654/11/0)

---

Running the above query on your sample data you will get an output like below:

```
| id |  name |
|----|-------|
|  1 |   Tom |
|  4 | Tommy |
|  5 |   Tom |
|  8 | Tommy |
```

**Explanation:**

**1)** First sort the data based on `name` in ascending order

```
    SELECT 
     id,
     `name`
    FROM your_table
    WHERE `name` IN ('Tom','Tommy')
    ORDER BY `name`
```

**Result:**

```
id  name
1   Tom
5   Tom
6   Tom
4   Tommy
8   Tommy
```

**2)** `@prevName` variable will track if the name is already seen before.

**3)** `@nameRank` variable will assign a rank number for each name. If the current name is already a seen one then it will assign an incremented number to it. (like roll number).

**4)** With the help of the above two variables the intermediate table would look like below:

```
id  name   rank
1   Tom     0 (seen first time so rank = 0)
5   Tom     1 (seen second time so rank = rank + 1 ; rank = 1)
6   Tom     2 (seen third time so rank = 2)
4   Tommy   0 (seen first time so rank = 0)
8   Tommy   1 (seen second time so rank = 1)
```

**5)** Since you want at most two entries per name so that you need to filter these data based on `rank < 2`

Answer (score 0):

Why you do not use `union` like this:

```
(SELECT id FROM table WHERE name like 'Tom' LIMIT 2)
UNION
(SELECT id FROM table WHERE name like 'Tommy' LIMIT 2)
```

Be careful to the `(` parentheses.

Comment: Need an `Order by name,id` at the end

Comment: Also you need one select query for each user in `WHERE IN (.....)` clause and later unionize them.

Comment: No you don't need an `Order By` clause because you already put the names in the order you want. @ringø

Comment: If you have a lot of `name` that you want to `union` them then you can build a `procedure` or build the query in the language you use like `PHP`.

Comment: Well in this case you need at least an `order by id` in each of the queries or the IDs may come in a different order (OP suggests IDs are ordered ASC for each name)